# Does After Update Trigger Fire after After Insert

Tags: apex, trigger

Does Afterupdate trigger fire automatically after afterInsert on same object?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, Both insert and Update events are independent execution contexts.

IsInsert Returns true if this trigger was fired due to an insert operation, from the Salesforce user interface, Apex, or the API.

IsUpdate Returns true if this trigger was fired due to an update operation(i.e.field update on existing records), from the Salesforce user interface, Apex, or the API.

Refer the similar question [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/trigger-behaviour-with-insert-and-update-in-same-execution-context).